# Threading errors in python code?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, matplotlib, python-3.6, python-multithreading

So I am writing a code for live mapping of a dataset which is a csv file. The data is in form ("string",integer). Originally It had to be ran as two different programs so I thought to thread both of them and run them as a single program. Code is:

```
import _thread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import csv
import time

def firstfunc(a):
    count=0
    with open('airtabletest.txt','r') as dataset:
        line=csv.reader(dataset)
        arr=[]
        for row in line:
            if(len(arr)>=9):
                arr.clear()
            for i in range(1,10):
                arr.append(int(row[i]))
            t=time.time()+3
            while(t>time.time()):
                    pass
            if(count>=8):
                with open('live_graph1','r') as file:
                    lines=file.readlines()
                with open('live_graph1','w') as csvfile:
                    csvfile.writelines(lines[1:])
            with open('live_graph1','a+') as file:
                arr2=[]
                writer=csv.writer(file)
                arr2.append(row[0][11:])
                arr2.append(sum(arr)/10)
                writer.writerow(arr2)
                count+=1

def secondfunc(b):
    style.use('fivethirtyeight')

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    def animate(i):
        xs = []
        ys = []
        count=0
        label=[]
        with open('live_graph1','r') as file:
            reader=csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                if(len(row) == 2):
                    x = float(row[1])
                    xs.append(count)
                    ys.append(x)
                    label.append(row[0])
                    count+=1
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.set_xticks(xs)
            ax1.set_xticklabels(label)
            ax1.plot(xs,ys)
            fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()

def main():
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(secondfunc,(Thread2,))
        _thread.start_new_thread(firstfunc,(tHREAD1,))
    except RuntimeError:
        pass

    while 1:
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':main()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  File "test.py", line 65
    while 1:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even if suppose for a time being I remove the while loop, then the error is:

```
  File "test.py", line 66
    if __name__=='__main__':main()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

As fas as I know, the syntax was okay. Can anyone please explain wht am I doing wrong?
Edit: As some answers suggested, I added the except statement. Then it asked for 2 arguments in _thread.start_new_thread function. After doing so, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 71, in <module>
    if __name__=='__main__':main()
  File "test.py", line 63, in main
    _thread.start_new_thread(secondfunc,(Thread2,))
NameError: name 'Thread2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue really is after the except adjustment, is that you are calling the function in a thread without passing any arguments as thread require both arguments and function to work otherwise it throws error that need two only given one arg so in order to fix that we can pass an empty tuple as arg if our functions take no arguments.

so what was

```
_thread.start_new_thread(firstfunc,)
```

is now this

```
_thread.start_new_thread(firstfunc,())
```

This should work

import _thread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import csv
import time

```
def firstfunc():
    count=0
    with open('airtabletest.txt','r') as dataset:
        line=csv.reader(dataset)
        arr=[]
        for row in line:
            if(len(arr)>=9):
                arr.clear()
            for i in range(1,10):
                arr.append(int(row[i]))
            t=time.time()+3
            while(t>time.time()):
                    pass
            if(count>=8):
                with open('live_graph1','r') as file:
                    lines=file.readlines()
                with open('live_graph1','w') as csvfile:
                    csvfile.writelines(lines[1:])
            with open('live_graph1','a+') as file:
                arr2=[]
                writer=csv.writer(file)
                arr2.append(row[0][11:])
                arr2.append(sum(arr)/10)
                writer.writerow(arr2)
                count+=1

def secondfunc():
    style.use('fivethirtyeight')

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    def animate(i):
        xs = []
        ys = []
        count=0
        label=[]
        with open('live_graph1','r') as file:
            reader=csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                if(len(row) == 2):
                    x = float(row[1])
                    xs.append(count)
                    ys.append(x)
                    label.append(row[0])
                    count+=1
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.set_xticks(xs)
            ax1.set_xticklabels(label)
            ax1.plot(xs,ys)
            fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()

def main():
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(secondfunc,())
        _thread.start_new_thread(firstfunc,())
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
    while 1:
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':main()
```

why your code is giving a syntax error is because you are required to specify what to do if **try** fail. i.e. must specify **except:**

also I believe in your code you have while 1 that will always return to be true and it seems to be not doing anything at all

Comment: I specified except and it printed the given text which means there was some kind of error. What I wanted to know was to how to resolve it.

Comment: editing the code to fix the errors and also capture and print the kind of error that occurs

Comment: I just edited the code for except statement. Please view it. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @ArohanAjit before that please checkout the explanation at the top of the recent edit

Comment: looked at the code @ArohanAjit what is the Thread1 and Thread2 doing there ????  I

Comment: Thanks! that worked, although we are not supposed to write commen for thanking but still you really helped me out there. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome, although I will still like to know why is the while loop there, please share when you get time

Comment: actually I watched in an online tutorial that while loop is need so that the program shall run for entire duration of both modules. As for the thread 1 and thread 2, just as you passed empty tuple, I tried to pass a non empty just it wont be doing anything

Answer (score 0):

How about adding

```
except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

or something similar after the try?

Comment: Tried that, another error popped up. This time they showed start new thread expected 2 arguments, when I gave em, it showed argument not defined.